# Erlang: Error in converting back from base 2 to decimal using # notation

Tags: erlang

To get the decimal equivalent of a number N in base B, I can do `B#N`, so `16#F` outputs `15`, and `2#1111` outputs 15 too.

To convert a number (say 15) from decimal to binary, I can do `integer_to_list(15,2)` which outputs `"1111"`, which can be made into a number by doing `list_to_integer`. So, doing `list_to_integer(integer_to_list(15,2)) + 1.` is perfectly valid and outputs `1112`.

I check that `is_integer` and `is_number` checks out to `true` for `list_to_integer(integer_to_list(15,2))` and I am also able to convert back doing `list_to_integer(integer_to_list(15,2), 2)` and get back `15`.

But when I try to do `2#list_to_integer(integer_to_list(15,2))`, why does it give me an error `*1: illegal integer` instead of `15`?

Comment: On trying further, I see that if I do `2#11` I get `3` but if I do `Var = 11` followed by `2#Var` I get an error. Seems like the compiler does special handling on seeing the hash sign, and anything  (e.g. a variable) that isn't obviously in the right base gives an error..

Comment: sorry, I made typo when wrote first comment(ofc 2#15 hasn't any sense I mean 12#5), so I removed it before then look your answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and despite the typo, it gave me the idea to try further (and get the result that I mentioned in my previous comment). So, spasiba :-)

Comment: So in this case meaning '#' can't be applying for any rest option of using this symbol (not a record and not a map) and it obvious error because it's not a valid expression.

Comment: And if dig into some more - integer is [atomic literal](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/absform.html#id93954) and base#value is single expression not a complex expression like (#(Base(),Value())).

Comment: actually, in this case, I think it should not be read as just `#` but as `B#`. Just a `#` is for records/maps. But `B#` means _a number in base B_. So, `2#1000` = `3#22` = `4#20`. The interesting part, as I mentioned earlier, is that `B#` can be followed by a string of digits but NOT even a variable representing that same string of digits: `2#1000` is valid but `X=1000` and then `2#X` is invalid. Similarly, `2#22` is also invalid. So my guess is that the compiler throws an error on seeing the variable in `2#X` because X may or may not be an appropriate number in base 2.

Comment: "base#value is single expression not a complex expression" ... indeed, it seems we were both writing the same conclusion at the same time, so i missed your comment before posting mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164864/discussion-between-atomic-alarm-and-yogesch).

Comment: Sorry, 6 am here, bed time..... many thanks for helping figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing here:

```
2> Name = "Yogesch".
"Yogesch"

3> "Name".
"Name"
4> 

8> "list_to_integer(integer_to_list(10))".
"list_to_integer(integer_to_list(10))"
```

Every computer programming language has syntax rules.  The syntax `2#10101` is for *integer literals*.  Notably, `2#` is not the name of a function, so you can't write `2#("1010")` nor:

```
10> X = "1010".
"1010"

11> 2#(X).
* 1: illegal integer
```

`2#` and `a space` are the delimiters for an integer literal just like quotes are the delimiters for a string (which is then interpreted as a list of integers).

Comment: 'N#' isn't a function but an integer literal. All my confusion stemmed from supposing otherwise. It did, after all, give the impression of "doing something" (like a function): converting from one base to another. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Yogesch,  You're welcome. Also note that double quotes, e.g. `"abc"`, convert the characters to the list `[97,98,99]`.